# Record audio and video from webcam java

Tags: java, audio-recording, video-recording

This is a program to record audio and video using jxcapture API. There is a error while running it. Can someone help me to figure out this problem.

```
   import com.teamdev.jxcapture.Codec;
   import com.teamdev.jxcapture.EncodingParameters;
   import com.teamdev.jxcapture.VideoCapture;
   import com.teamdev.jxcapture.audio.AudioCodec;
   import com.teamdev.jxcapture.audio.AudioEncodingParameters;
   import com.teamdev.jxcapture.audio.AudioSource;
   import com.teamdev.jxcapture.video.VideoFormat;
   import com.teamdev.jxcapture.video.VideoSource;

   import java.io.File;
   import java.util.List;


 public class CaptureVideoFromWebCameraWithAudio {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    VideoCapture videoCapture = VideoCapture.create(VideoFormat.MP4);

    List<VideoSource> availableVideoSources = VideoSource.getAvailable();
    System.out.println("availableVideoSources = " + availableVideoSources);

    if (availableVideoSources.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("No external video sources available");
    }

    VideoSource webCamera = availableVideoSources.get(0);
    System.out.println("webCamera = " + webCamera);

    videoCapture.setVideoSource(webCamera);

    List<Codec> videoCodecs = videoCapture.getVideoCodecs();
    Codec videoCodec = videoCodecs.get(2);
    System.out.println("videoCodec = " + videoCodec);

    EncodingParameters encodingParameters = new EncodingParameters(new File("WebCamera.MP4"));
    encodingParameters.setBitrate(500000);
    encodingParameters.setFramerate(10);
    encodingParameters.setKeyFrameInterval(1);
    encodingParameters.setCodec(videoCodec);

    System.out.println("Available audio recording sources:");
    List<AudioSource> audioSources = AudioSource.getAvailable();
    for (AudioSource audioSource : audioSources) {
        System.out.println("audioSource = " + audioSource);
    }
    if (audioSources.isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("No audio sources available");
    } else {
        AudioSource audioSource = audioSources.get(0);
        System.out.println("Selected audio source = " + audioSource);
        videoCapture.setAudioSource(audioSource);

        List<AudioCodec> audioCodecs = videoCapture.getAudioCodecs();
        if (audioSources.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("No audio codecs available");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Available audio codecs:");
            for (AudioCodec audioCodec : audioCodecs) {
                System.out.println("audioCodec = " + audioCodec);
            }

            // Enable and configure audio encoding
            AudioEncodingParameters audioEncoding = new AudioEncodingParameters();

            AudioCodec audioCodec = audioCodecs.get(0);
            System.out.println("Selected audio codec = " + audioCodec);
            audioEncoding.setCodec(audioCodec);

            encodingParameters.setAudioEncoding(audioEncoding);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("encodingParameters = " + encodingParameters);

    videoCapture.start(encodingParameters);
    System.out.println("Recording started. Press 'Enter' to pause.");
    System.in.read();
    videoCapture.pause();
    System.out.println("Recording started. Press 'Enter' to resume.");
    System.in.read();
    videoCapture.start();
    System.out.println("Recording started. Press 'Enter' to stop.");
    System.in.read();
    videoCapture.stop();
    System.out.println("Done.");
  }
  }
```

error

```
Run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/slf4j/LoggerFactory 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

While you have asked this question a long time ago, try adding this maven dependency to your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

If you do not use maven, get the jar from here: https://www.slf4j.org/download.html

Comment: It might be useful to add one of slf4j implementations too (like simple or logback).